# THREE.js no shadows

Tags: three.js

I'm currently trying to get into THREE.js a bit and I'm obviously following tutorials and examples but
even after all that I can't seem to get shadows working.

`shadowMap.enabled` is set to true, `castShadow` is set on the cube beneath the light and `receiveShadow` is set to true on the floor.

My attempt is visible on https://mroman.ch/shadows/cg.html

[image]

```
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas,'antialias':true});
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;




  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 1;  
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 8*0.2;
  camera.position.y = 2*0.2;

  const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  controls.update();

  const sz = 0.2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 2;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(0, 2*sz, 2*sz);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
    var d = 200;

    light.shadow.cameraLeft = -d;
    light.shadow.cameraRight = d;
    light.shadow.cameraTop = d;
    light.shadow.cameraBottom = -d;

    light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;

    const helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera );
    scene.add( helper );

    scene.add(light);
  }

  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "brown"});
  const mat_green = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:"green"});
  const mat_floor = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:"gray"});

  const group = new THREE.Group();



  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(sz/2,sz/1.5,3*sz,8,8);
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.position.set(0,sz,0);
  group.add(cube);



  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(sz,sz,sz);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_green);
  cube.position.set(0.0,3*sz,0);
  group.add(cube);

  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(sz);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_green);
  cube.position.set(sz,3*sz,0);
  group.add(cube);

  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(sz);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_green);
  cube.position.set(-sz,3*sz,0);
  group.add(cube);

  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(sz);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_green);
  cube.position.set(0.0,3*sz,sz);
  group.add(cube);

  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(sz);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_green);
  cube.position.set(0.0,3*sz,-sz);
  group.add(cube);

  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(sz);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_green);
  cube.position.set(0.0,4*sz,0.0);
  group.add(cube);

  const floor = new THREE.Group();

  for(var x = -4; x <= 4; x++) {
   for(var z = -4; z <= 4; z++) {
     geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(sz,sz,sz);
     cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_floor);
     cube.position.set(x*sz,-sz,z*sz);
     cube.receiveShadow = true;
     floor.add(cube);
   }
  }



  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(sz, sz, sz);
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat_floor);
  cube.position.set(0,sz,2*sz);
  cube.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(cube);

  scene.add(group);
  scene.add(floor);


  function render(time) {
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

Can anybody point out where I got it wrong?

Comment: I've included image and code from your link to make question self-containing. Please let me know if everything is ok with it

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. Yes, this is a much better question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of curiosity, tried ThreeJs for the first time to answer this question, so might not be good enough in explanation.

Result

[image: Result]

To fix cube shadow I changed this:

```
const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
light.position.set(0, 2*sz, 2*sz);
```

To this:

```
const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
light.position.set(0, 3 * sz, 3 * sz);
```

I guess it was just issue with light emitter being inside of the cube?

And cylinder just misses property to cast shadow. I would recommend changing `cube` variable name to something more meaningful.

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(sz / 2, sz / 1.5, 3 * sz, 8, 8);
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.castShadow = true;
```

Comment: Yeh I just played around with moving that cube and noticed that when it moves away from the light source it suddenly casts shadow. This explains why. It's too close to the light source.